# Using TinyMCE uploading images to a backend

Tags: reactjs, image, flask, tinymce, blob

I am trying to use the rich text editor TinyMCE for a blog platform I am currently working on.
I am also using React with a Flask backend. A
User should be able to create a blog entry with the editor and also use/ upload images.
I got everything setup but I don't know how to store the images in my backend so you can save a blog with all it's content.
I got this callback function from their documentation but I do not really understand what's happening there and if it is enough to send the file object to my backend and store it in the database.

```
       file_picker_callback: function (cb, value, meta) {
                var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.setAttribute("type", "file");
                input.setAttribute("accept", "image/png , image/jpg");

                input.onchange = function () {
                  var file = this.files[0];

                  var reader = new FileReader();
                  reader.onload = function () {
                    var id = "blobid" + new Date().getTime();
                    var blobCache =
                      window.tinymce.activeEditor.editorUpload.blobCache;
                    var base64 = reader.result.split(",")[1];
                    var blobInfo = blobCache.create(id, file, base64);
                    blobCache.add(blobInfo);

                    /* call the callback and populate the Title field with the file name */
                    cb(blobInfo.blobUri(), { title: file.name });
                  };
                  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                  console.log(file);
                };
```

This is the console.log(file) output

```
File {name: "wlogLogo.png", lastModified: 1590578382000, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 4591, type: "image/png", …}
```